# Screen Scraping with PHP and XPath

Tags: php, xpath, screen-scraping

Does anyone know how to maintain text formatting when using XPath to extract data?

I am currently extracting all blocks

`<div class="info">
<h5>title</h5>
text <a href="somelink">anchor</a>
</div>`

from a page. The problem is when I access the nodeValue, I can only get plain text. How can I capture the contents including formatting, i.e. the h5 and a still in the code?

Thanks in advance. I have searched every combination imaginable on Google and no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have it as a DomElement $element as part of a DomDocument $dom then you will want to do something like:

```
$string = $dom->saveXml($element);
```

The NodeValue of an element is really the textual value, not the structured XML.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to Ciaran McNulty answer

You can do the same in SimpleXml like:

```
$simplexml->node->asXml(); // saveXml() is now an alias
```

And to expand on the quote

> The NodeValue of an element is really the textual value, not the structured XML.

You can think of your node as follows:

```
<div class="info">
    <__toString()> </__toString()>
    <h5>title</h5>
    <__toString()> text </__toString()>
    <a href="somelink">anchor</a>
    <__toString()> </__toString()>
</div>
```

Where the call to `$element->nodeValue` is like calling `$element->__toString()` which would only get the __toString() elements. The imaginary `__toString()` I created is officially defined as an [`XML_TEXT_NODE`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/domxml.constants.php).

Answer (score 1):

**The [XPath language](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) is designed to be embedded in another language (such as DOM API, XSLT, XQuery, ...) and cannot be used standalone**. The original question does not specify what is the desired embedding.

**Below is a very simple and short solution when XPath is embedded in [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)**.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='info']">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this xml document**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="info">
            <h1>title1</h1> text1
            <a href="somelink1">anchor1</a>
        </div>
        Something else here
        <div class="info">
            <h2>title2</h2> text2
            <a href="somelink2">anchor2</a>
        </div>
        Something else here
        <div class="info">
            <h3>title3</h3> text3
            <a href="somelink3">anchor3</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<div class="info">
  <h1>title1</h1> text1
    <a href="somelink1">anchor1</a>
</div>
        Something else here
<div class="info">
  <h2>title2</h2> text2
  <a href="somelink2">anchor2</a>
</div>
        Something else here
<div class="info">
  <h3>title3</h3> text3
  <a href="somelink3">anchor3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure your xpath query 'ends' at the `<div class="info">`.  However, because of the way XPath works, you'll still get all of the 'subtags' in separate nodes.  You'll just need to concatenate them.

You could also use XPath's [join](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp) functionality, though, as I haven't used it, I can't say what problems you might run in to.

Answer (score 0):

`div/node()` should do the trick.

Example input:

```
<div class="info">
  some <h5>title</h5> text <a href="somelink">anchor</a> more text
</div>
```

Example XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
        <newtag>
                <xsl:copy-of select="div/node()"/>
        </newtag>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<newtag> some<h5>title</h5> text <a href="somelink">anchor</a> more text</newtag>
```